# iOS Photos Framework data UTI or format when image is in cloud

Tags: ios, objective-c, photosframework

I'm upgrading my GIF app to use the iOS 8 Photos Framework and basically I want to find all the user's GIFs in their photo library and display them. Worked great with `ALAssetLibrary` before iCloud Photo Library's 'optimise storage' came into play as now users can have a large amount of their images in the cloud, hence needing to use the Photos Framework to get at them Unfortunately it seems that you can't tell if a `PHAsset` is GIF or a normal static image until you've downloaded it from the cloud.... Which is going to make my app pretty lame when you have zero or poor network connection...

This is the code I use to attempt to get only the GIFs:

```
PHFetchOptions* fetchOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
            fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES]];
            PHFetchResult *allPhotosResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options: fetchOptions];

            //   Get assets from the PHFetchResult object
            [allPhotosResult enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAsset *asset, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                //NSLog(@"asset %@", asset);
                PHImageRequestOptions* options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
                options.synchronous = YES;
                options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeFastFormat;
[imageManager requestImageDataForAsset: asset options: options resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info) {

// when the item is in the cloud dataUTI is nil so I can't check what format it is...

}
```

The info dictionary contains some undocumented keys:

- `PHImageResultDeliveredImageFormatKey`
- `PHImageResultWantedImageFormat`

Which I've seen have values of 9999, 9998 and 40xx. But they don't particularly seem to correlate with whether the image is a GIF or not so must relate to something else entirely...

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there just isn't a way to figure this out without pulling down the images from the cloud and checking after. I'm updating my app to do that but to remember the type of each image against the `PHAsset`'s `localIdentifier` so that it only needs to do it once.

If you take this approach you might also want to avoid `PHAsset`s which represent burst, HDR or panorama images as they're not going to be gifs (obviously exclude videos too!)

Answer (score 0):

use this options!

```
PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc]init];
    options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;
    options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
```

Comment: That requires the image to be downloaded from the cloud before knowing anything about it, which is the problem I'm trying to avoid... I want to know the PHAsset's format before attempting any network activity but it doesn't seem to be exposed... Only whether the asset is an image or video :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution but only for IOS 9, they have added a new struct

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, PHAssetSourceType) {
 PHAssetSourceTypeNone            = 0,
 PHAssetSourceTypeUserLibrary     = (1UL << 0),
 PHAssetSourceTypeCloudShared     = (1UL << 1),
 PHAssetSourceTypeiTunesSynced    = (1UL << 2),
} NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);
```

also

```
Added PHAssetResourceType [enum]
Added PHAssetResourceType.AdjustmentBasePhoto
Added PHAssetResourceType.AdjustmentData
Added PHAssetResourceType.AlternatePhoto
Added PHAssetResourceType.Audio
Added PHAssetResourceType.FullSizePhoto
Added PHAssetResourceType.FullSizeVideo
Added PHAssetResourceType.Photo
Added PHAssetResourceType.Video
```

Comment: That doesn't help as it just tells you where it's from, which you can easily find out already. The issue is finding out what file extension an image in the cloud has, to find gifs without having to check them all

Comment: OK I misunderstood the issue perhaps you could answer my question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/30888329/1463518