# Getting PHAssetSource IOS 8

Tags: ios

In the PhotoFramework for IOS 9 ,they have a handy struct for the source type.

Is there anyway to identify an assets source type on IOS 8 ?

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, PHAssetSourceType) {
 PHAssetSourceTypeNone            = 0,
 PHAssetSourceTypeUserLibrary     = (1UL << 0),
 PHAssetSourceTypeCloudShared     = (1UL << 1),
 PHAssetSourceTypeiTunesSynced    = (1UL << 2),
} NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this code. If you ask for the image without letting it use network access it will return nil if the image is in the cloud.

```
PHFetchOptions* fetchOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
            PHFetchResult *allPhotosResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options: fetchOptions];

            //   Get assets from the PHFetchResult object
            [allPhotosResult enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAsset *asset, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                //NSLog(@"asset %@", asset);
                PHImageRequestOptions* options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
                options.allowNetworkAccess = NO; // <<<< don't allow network access to determine if it's in the cloud or not
                options.synchronous = YES; // depends on your situation
                options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeFastFormat; 
[imageManager requestImageDataForAsset: asset options: options resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info) {

// if imageData is nil then it's not on the device, likely in the cloud, otherwise it's local

}
```

Comment: Thanks, That is what I had thought of doing, it just seemed such a round about way of determining it.